# How to generate C code from Python?

Tags: python, c, jinja2, template-meta-programming, mako

I am writing an embedded algorithm. Currently I have lookup tables that are hard-coded:

```
static const int32_t sine[65536] = {
    ...
}
```

The algorithm should be portable on different platforms but, the lookup table length changes depending on the configuration and on the destination platform.

My current solution uses mako-render (Mako is much faster than Jinja2) as follow:

```
<%!
import os
import algo  # Local module that contains tools to generate coefs.
from numpy import sin, linspace, pi

a, b, c, d, e = algo.coefficients(os.environ['ALGO_MODE'])
%>

static inline float poly(float x)
{
    return x * ( x * ( x * ( x * ${a} + ${b}) + ${c}) + ${d}) + ${e};
}

float sine[] = {
% for y in sin(linspace(0, 2 * pi, 2 ** 16)):
    ${y},
% endfor
};
```

In my Makefile I use this:

```
in: $(IN)
$(IN): build/headers/%: src/%.in
    mkdir -p $(dir $@)
    PYTHONPATH=.:$$PYTHONPATH mako-render $< > $@ || true
```

I like this solution because I can easily generate C code from Python results:

- Filter coefficients
- Lookup tables
- Dynamic types
- ...

The main drawbacks are:

- None of the template engine I have found works well with C code

  - Jinja has a syntax with a lot of curly braces, confusing in C
  - Mako has a weird hybrid syntax mix xml (`<% %>`), shell (`${}`), mako (`%`).
- Using the `.in` extension for my template could be confusing because this extension is already used by autotools and CMake.

Meta-programming / Code generation are something becoming very popular and in my field of work I almost need to use such magic everyday. I am surprised that no other native solutions as old as `grep` exist (please don't mention M4 :)).

What other solution can I use to populate C *templates* with data generated from an external script? Am I missing any real magic here?

Comment: This is perhaps not exactly what you are looking for, but you know that you can change the tags in `jinja2` right? Look at http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/2.10/api/#high-level-api There it is shown how to change e.g. the `block_start_sting` and all other tags.

Comment: Yes I know that, but mako as several advantages: there is a builtin mako-render command line interface and you can execute python code directly from the template, which is not possible in jinja